# filling in the hourly time gaps in a resultset

Tags: sql-server, t-sql, sql-server-2008

In some of the hours I insert data to DB with timestamp. I want to have hourly view with rows without records filled with last record data :

**Table**

```
DateTime Value  
12     4  
15     6
```

**Desired Result**

```
DateTime Value  
12       4  
13       4  
14       4  
15       6  
16       6
```

It should be possible, but I can't think about any effective way..

How can this be done?

Comment: What is your current query? Are you using BETWEEN?

Comment: @marc_s: I deleted my answer just before I saw your comment. You are welcome to look at the history of my answer and repost it if you wish. I'm not sure that it will help much though.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

OK having misread the question once and provided an answer that leaves the gaps efficiently;  in order to get the last value out in sql you will need to loop the data which is less efficient.

```
Create Table tblMyValues (MyHours int, MyValue int)
Insert into tblMyValues select 12, 4
Insert into tblMyValues select 15, 6
Insert into tblMyValues select 15, 6


Create Table tblResult (MyHour int, ReportValue Int)

Declare @i Int = 0, @LastValue Int
While @i <= 24
Begin

select @i = @i + 1
Select @LastValue = coalesce(MyValue, @LastValue)
From tblMyValues
Where MyHours = @i

    insert into tblResult 
    Select @i, @LastValue

End

select * from tblResult
drop table tblMyValues
drop table tblResult
```

This returns

```
MyHour      ReportValue
----------- -----------
1           NULL
2           NULL
3           NULL
4           NULL
5           NULL
6           NULL
7           NULL
8           NULL
9           NULL
10          NULL
11          NULL
12          4
13          4
14          4
15          6
16          6
17          6
18          6
19          6
20          6
21          6
22          6
23          6
24          6
```

Comment: well, I knew I could do it with loop - looks like i'll have to go this way.   But I thought it is possible via standart selects and joins (it is better to avoid loops, IMHO).  Thnaks for answer!  BR, bala

Answer (score 1):

This requires a second table. It would have a row for every hourly
timestamps, regardless of whether there are rows for that timestamps for
the table you described.

Say your table is :

`CREATE TABLE [dbo].[TimeStamp](
    [DateTimeHour] [int] NULL,
    [Value] [int] NULL
)`

And new Table is :

`CREATE TABLE [dbo].[DateTimeTally](
    [DateTimeHour] [int] NULL
)`

Insert your rows into table TimeStamp and rows 0-23 into table DateTimeTally.
So, the final query is :

```
SELECT DateTimeHour,
        ISNULL((SELECT VALUE FROM TimeStamp ST1 WHERE ST1.DateTimeHour = 
            (SELECT MAX(DateTimeHour)FROM TimeStamp ST2 
                             WHERE ST2.DateTimeHour <= 
                              A.DateTimeHour)),0) Value --Not equal, actually less than or equal
 FROM
(SELECT D.DateTimeHour DateTimeHour,T.Value Value FROM TimeStamp T
        RIGHT OUTER JOIN DateTimeTally D
        ON(T.DateTimeHour = D.DateTimeHour))A
```

This returns :

```
DateTimeHour      Value
----------- -----------
0           0
1           0
2           0
3           0
4           0
5           0
6           0
7           0
8           0
9           0
10          0
11          0
12          4
13          4
14          4
15          6
16          6
17          6
18          6
19          6
20          6
21          6
22          6
23          6
```

Hope that helps :)

Comment: if you think this was the best answer, mark it as answer or if that helps, mark it as useful. That will surely interest people to help you more :-)