# How to fill the gaps?

Tags: sql, sql-server-2005, date

Assuming I have two records, both with a date and a count:

```
--Date--                   --Count--
2011-09-20 00:00:00        5
2011-09-16 00:00:00        8
```

How would you select this for filling the time gaps, always taking the last previous record?

So the output would be:

```
--Date--                   --Count--
2011-09-20 00:00:00        5
2011-09-19 00:00:00        8
2011-09-18 00:00:00        8
2011-09-17 00:00:00        8
2011-09-16 00:00:00        8
```

I couldn't figure out a neat solution for this, yet.
I guess this could be done with DATEDIFF, and a for-loop, but I hope this can be done easier.

Comment: They are a lot of literature, search for 'sql gap and islands': sample: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa175780(v=sql.80).aspx

Comment: possible duplicate of [filling in the hourly time gaps in a resultset](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4504231/filling-in-the-hourly-time-gaps-in-a-resultset)

Comment: @danihp Thank you. I will have a closer look at it.

Comment: @HABO it's not hourly, it's daily. But thanks for the link!

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You have 2 issues you're trying to resolve.  The first issue is how to fill the gaps. The second issue is populating the Count field for those missing records.

Issue 1: This can be resolved by either using a `Dates Lookup table` or by creating a `recursive common table expression`.  I would recommend creating a Dates Lookup table for this if that is an option.  If you cannot create such a table, then you're going to need something like this.

```
WITH CTE AS (
  SELECT MAX(dt) maxdate, MIN(dt) mindate
  FROM yourtable
  ),
RecursiveCTE AS (
  SELECT mindate dtfield
  FROM CTE
  UNION ALL
  SELECT DATEADD(day, 1, dtfield)
  FROM RecursiveCTE R 
    JOIN CTE T
      ON R.dtfield < T.maxdate
  )
```

That should create you a list of dates starting with the `MIN` date in your table and ending in the `MAX`.

Issue 2: Here is where a `correlated subquery` would come in handy (as much as I generally stay away from them) to get the last cnt from your original table:

```
SELECT r.dtfield, 
   (SELECT TOP 1 cnt
    FROM yourtable 
    WHERE dt <= r.dtfield 
    ORDER BY dt DESC) cnt
FROM RecursiveCTE r
```

- [SQL Fiddle Demo](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/4d37c/2)

Answer (score 1):

My solution goes like this.

Step 1: Have a Date table which has all the dates. - you can use many methods ex: [Get a list of dates between two dates](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/510012/get-a-list-of-dates-between-two-dates)

Step 2: Do a Left outer from the date table to your result set. - which would result you with the below resultset: Call this table as "TEST_DATE_COUnt"

```
--Date--                   --Count--
2011-09-20 00:00:00        5
2011-09-19 00:00:00        0
2011-09-18 00:00:00        0
2011-09-17 00:00:00        0
2011-09-16 00:00:00        8
```

Step 3: Do a Recursive query like below:

```
SELECT t1.date_x, t1.count_x,
   (case when count_x=0 then (SELECT max(COUNT_X)
    FROM TEST_DATE_COUNT r 
    WHERE r.DATE_X <= t1.DATE_X) 
    else COUNT_X
    end) 
    cnt
FROM TEST_DATE_COUNT t1
```

Please let me know if this works. I tested and it worked.

Comment: Thank you! The problem is that Recursion has a limitation of 100. Do you know how to avoid that problem?

Comment: You can use `OPTION (MAXRECURSION 0);` Can you paste the last query you have. I can analyze and tell you. Thanks.

Comment: The absolute maximum of MAXRECURSION would be 32767. Thank you.