# Arithmetic overflow error converting expression to data type datetime - SSRS

Tags: sql-server, datetime, stored-procedures, reporting-services

I have an historian database with 3 columns (id, SampleValue and SampleDateTime) that records the SampleValue of all id when their value changes. What I want to do is to build a report, each day, that gives me the SampleValue each minute for a specific id even if the value doesn't change. I manage to build something with the help of this article [How to fill the gaps?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16819365/how-to-fill-the-gaps?answertab=votes#tab-top). I am doing it in a stored procedure, so I'll be able to use that stored procedure, in Microsoft Visual Studio (SSRS Report Designer), to build my report. Here is my code:

```
create proc test13_GetHist as
WITH CTE AS (
  SELECT max(Getdate()) maxdate, min(DATEADD(day, 1, Getdate())) mindate
  FROM Historian_Database.dbo.NumericSamples 
  WHERE TagID=41
  ),
RecursiveCTE AS (
  SELECT mindate dtfield
  FROM CTE
  UNION ALL
  SELECT DATEADD(minute, 1, dtfield)
  FROM RecursiveCTE R 
    JOIN CTE T
      ON R.dtfield < T.maxdate
  )
SELECT r.dtfield, 
 (SELECT TOP 1 SampleValue
    FROM Historian_Database.dbo.NumericSamples
    WHERE SampleDateTime <= r.dtfield ORDER BY SampleDateTime DESC) SampleValue
FROM RecursiveCTE r
ORDER BY dtfield asc
OPTION (MAXRECURSION 0);
```

SampleValue is float type, id is int type and SampleDateTime is bigint or datetime2.
My problem is that I get this error message when I am trying to preview my report : "An error occured during local report processing. An error has occured during report processing. Cannot read the next data row for the dataset DataSet2. Arithmetic overflow error converting expression to data type datetime."

I don't know what to do with that error.

Any help would really be appreciated.

Thank,

Emanuel

Comment: `SELECT max(Getdate()) maxdate, min(DATEADD(day, 1, Getdate())) mindate`, this is totally unnecessary

Comment: You get this error when you try to convert something to a datetime that cannot be (out of range, or invalid date).   Analyze the output of your RecursiveCTE to see what values you are trying to generate.  And what is the definition of "dtfield"?

Comment: Thanks, but I managed to do what I wanted another way.