# SQL. I'm looking for a way to populate the values between numbers with duplicate values

Tags: sql

SequentialOrder cost

```
1    NULL
2    NULL
3    NULL
4    NULL
5    NULL
6    NULL
7    5.766
8    NULL
9    5.767
```

I am using Sql Server 2008 R2. I am looking for a way to duplicate down the values for the lower "sequential orders" when the cost doesn't exist. I tried learning from this example ([How to fill the gaps?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16819365/how-to-fill-the-gaps)) but failed.   For example, I want to turn the above table into something that resembles the following:

SequentialOrder cost

```
1    5.766
2    5.766
3    5.766
4    5.766
5    5.766
6    5.766
7    5.766
8    5.767
9    5.767
```

Comment: It would definitely help if we knew what database you're using..  Some have partitioning functions that can do this sort of thing..

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. Just to let you know, it will be very much appreciated if you provide us with specific details when you ask questions on this site, as @MikeChristensen suggests above.

Answer (score 0):

If the numbers are always increasing, you can use the ANSI `min()` cumulative window function:

```
select t.*, min(cost) over (order by SequentialOrder desc)
from t;
```

EDIT:

Because the question is not tagged with a database, the most general solution is a correlated subquery.  It would look something like this:

```
select t.*,
       (select t2.cost
        from t t2
        where t2.cost is not null and t2.SequentialOrder >= t.SequentialOrder
        order by t2.SequentialOrder desc
        fetch first 1 row only
       ) as cost_notnull
from t;
```

Note that some databases use `TOP` or `LIMIT` or even something else instead of the ANSI standard `FETCH FIRST 1 ROW ONLY`.

Comment: Unfortunately they aren't and they happen at different intervals

Answer (score 0):

You may be able to try something like this:

```
select sequentialOrder, max(cost) over (partition by cost) as ubound 
from <orders_table>
order by sequentialOrder
```

In any case, you will have to look into partitioning and ordering with aggregate functions.

Answer (score 0):

You can use an `OUTER APPLY` to backfill values. For larger datasets you may want to limit how far you want to backfill as this kind of query tends to be very slow.

```
SELECT SequentialOrder,
       COALESCE(o.Cost, details.Cost) AS Cost 
FROM   dbo.data o
       OUTER APPLY ( SELECT TOP 1 Cost
                     FROM     dbo.data i
                     WHERE    Cost IS NOT NULL
                     AND i.SequentialOrder> o.SequentialOrder
                     ORDER BY  SequentialOrder ASC
                ) details
```

Answer (score 0):

For a given id - search for the first nearest record with non-null value and take its value:

```
declare @t table(id int, val decimal(10, 3))

insert into @t values(1, NULL)
insert into @t values(2, NULL)
insert into @t values(3, NULL)
insert into @t values(4, NULL)
insert into @t values(5, NULL)
insert into @t values(6, NULL)
insert into @t values(7, 5.766)
insert into @t values(8, NULL)
insert into @t values(9, 5.767)

select 
    t1.id,
    (select top 1 t2.val 
        from @t as t2 
        where t2.id >= t1.id and t2.val is not null
        order by t2.id) as val
from @t as t1
```